# What is the correct value for "certainty" in RSA key pair generation?

Tags: public-key, rsa, prime-numbers

I'm creating an RSA key pair in Bouncy Castle and need to specify an int value for certainty.  This [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3087049/328397) says it is a relative test for how prime the values are.

There is another answer that says this value should be adjusted relative to the key length.

**Question**

- What are the correct values for certainty relative to key length (how did you determine this?)
- What does it mean to say "certainty of x bits" of a number?  (If it's possible to sub-divide a number and certify bits, which bits are being certified?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Certainty of $x$ bits** means that the probability that something (in this case $p$ being prime) not being true is smaller than $2^{-x}$. This is the same probability as guessing a random $x$-bit value correctly on the first try, hence the name.

**How to select $x$**? We want the probability of $p$ (and $q$) not being prime to be small enough that a failure probability in this point is not larger than other ways the system could be broken - like guessing a symmetric key, factoring the modulus etc.

So here [a correspondence table of symmetric and asymmetric key sizes](http://www.keylength.com/) should help. Pick the same prime certainty as you would pick an symmetric key size accompanying your public key usage.

Comment: Also, your algorithmic probability of failure is physically bounded by the failure probability of your hardware, so for instance, a $2^{-512}$ probability of failure is quite overkill.

Comment: As a confirmation, the certainty in the question is traceable to that in a paragraph just _above_ [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#probablePrime%28int,%20java.util.Random%29), reading: "$\mathtt{certainty }$ - a measure of the uncertainty that the caller is willing to tolerate. The probability that the new BigInteger represents a prime number will exceed $(1-1/{2^{\mathtt{certainty}}})$. The execution time of this constructor is proportional to the value of this parameter."

Comment: Anybody, please, in English?

Comment: @JinKwon I think we wrote this in English, could you please tell us more exactly about your problem?